# unable to access an array via singleton

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, singleton

I need to pass an array from InGameLayer to AppDelegate, so here's what I did

in InGameLayer.h

```
@interface InGameLayer : CCLayer
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCArray *heroArray;
+(InGameLayer *)sharedInGameLayer;
```

in InGameLayer.m

```
static InGameLayer* sharedInGameLayer;
+(InGameLayer*)sharedInGameLayer
{
    if (sharedInGameLayer == nil)
    {
        sharedInGameLayer = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInGameLayer;
}

//add Object if the button is tapped
- (void)PlayerButton1Tapped:(id)sender
{
    CCSprite *hero =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hero.png"];
    [_heroArray addObject:hero];
}
```

in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    CCArray *heroArray = [InGameLayer sharedInGameLayer].heroArray;
    CCLOG(@"array = %d", heroArray.count);
}
```

And the problem is that array = 0, no matter how many Object I added to heroArray.
Please give me a hand for this problem. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You never create your array. Your property declaration autosynthesizes an instance variable `CCArray *_heroArray` and access methods for it. All instance variables are initialized with zeroes on object creation, and as you never store a pointer to an actual CCArray object in your instance variable, it stays `nil`.

In `init` method of your class you should do

```
_heroArray = [[CCArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hi, yes I have init my array like this in my init method. The problem is I didn't add my Object inside the init method. I want to user to add the object by clicking the button. And the Object never pass to the AppDelegate (the array is nil in AppDelegate). Can you please suggest a way to do this? Thank you for your reply